# Pass global service to child classes in Angular 2

Tags: angular, singleton, global-variables, angular2-services

I've got the main component that has 2 child components and a service. I do `bootstrap(Main, [MyService])`, however I want to have the functionality (possibility to call service functions) from these both child components. How should I pass one instance of this service from the parent component to my child components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't specify the provider of the service in the component, just include it in the constructor.

If you're providing the service in the bootstrap and want it to be a singleton, your component will look like this.

```js
@Component({
   template: '<child-component></child-component>',
   directives: [ChildComponent],
   providers: []  // no need to include the specify the service here
 })

export class MyComponent {
  /*even though you're injecting the service here, it will use the same
    instance provided in the bootstrap */

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    
  }
}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  providers: [] // no need to include the specify the service here
})

export class ChildComponent {
  //you can do this as long as you don't specify the service in the providers list
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
  }
}
```

Comment: I do that. In main component I can include a provider in constructor, but in child components I can't, I have an error. Maybe I should pass the provider from the parent component to a child one somehow ?

Comment: what error? It shouldn't be necessary to pass anything

Comment: I mean, why can't you include the service in child's constructor?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I just mistyped. Now everything works fine, however, the variable in the service has '2 states': for the 1st component and for the second one. I expected it to be like a singleton, to have something like a global variable

Comment: That only happens, if you still have that service in the `providers` array of the respective components.

Comment: It will. The key here are the providers. Whenever angular sees a service defined in the providers list it will create a new instance of the service.

Comment: I forgot to check it, thank you so much. I am ashamed that I couldn't manage with this problem

Comment: Don't be. But I highly recommend you to read the official documentation of angular's DI. It was a game change for me. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html